# WebSphere MQ Cluster Controller

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

Is it possible in WAS or on the MQ side to only ever have 1 active connection to a MQ and other passive connections?

That way I can avoid competing consumers for a queue but if a consumer fails, it would still allow for another competing consumer to connect. Like a heartbeat monitor for consumer health.

Scenerio:

1. Multiple WAS Server Consumers in a cluster
2. Only 1 MQ Queue Manager
3. Require only 1 active consumer due to message processing correlation. Order of messages is not important.

   - Anyway to send messages to only 1 active consumer while keeping other consumers passive?

I thought maybe a max open input count property on a queue would exist but did not see it.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your scenario a bit.  Do you currently have multiple instances of WAS consumers running? Is there only one MQ queue manager? Is your requirement to process messages on a single consumer due to message affinity or the need to process in a particular order?

Comment: Updated above. What do you mean by message affinity ?

Comment: Message Affinity means that messages are required to be processed in a certain order. One example is when there is a requirement to process messages in sequence in which they come.  MQ offers some suggestions for handling affinities. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q017780_.htm?lang=en

Comment: Queues do have a SHARE and NOSHARE parameter to specify whether multiple applications can get messages from a queue.  SHARE  More than one application instance can get messages from the queue.  NOSHARE Only a single application instance can get messages from the queue.  But I am not sure if this is the solution for you, perhaps someone with more WAS experience will answer.

Comment: That's a Good point. I'm not sure if it would keep other instances passive or throw a connection error. I will try it out.

Comment: Throws a warning saying object is in use but keeps the connection passive. When I shut down connection 1, connection 2 became active. I was using a spring message driven pojo. Not sure how a WAS mdb would react if it would disable the end-point. I'm not sure I like the idea of filling the logs with warning as method for HA if a server goes down. It does work though. However there might be an adverse affect of so many failed attempts connecting.

Comment: How is the consumer making the connection?  Is it using a connection factory?  I'm assuming the consumer is an application installed on WAS at the cluster level?

Comment: I'm using spring MDP because I require aggregation of messages. So yes it would be a connection factory setting that the channel adapter would use. Typically a WAS MDB though would use an activation spec which connects to the mq itself.